# Database design for flagging system

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I have a database which captures information relating to a patient for a medical practice. This information is spread across several tables:

1. Patient - For contact information
2. PatientMedicalHistory - For medical conditions unrelated to the current problem
3. PatientEpisode - Financial information for the current visit
4. PatientEpisodeReason - Stuff relating to why the patient is here today

I want to introduce a flag system, so that any messages will appear when bringing up the patient details. So for example, if the patient has had a heart attack previously this would need to be flagged (that info would be in PatientMedicalHistory).

My current approach is to set up a flag lookup table which defines the flag type, and the table/column that the flag is referring to and what the value would be in order to raise that flag:

```
CREATE TABLE FlagType
(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    TypeName NVARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
    Colour NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Urgency INT NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE Flag
(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    FlagTypeID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES FlagType(ID),
    TableName NVARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
    FieldName NVARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
    FlagValue NVARCHAR(300) NOT NULL
)
```

This seemed all very well, but then trying to write either a) a stored procedure that doesn't resemble a mess or b) a LINQ query that doesn't kill performance seems difficult.

Is there any alternatives to this? The issue is that the flag could be defined on any column in any of the tables above. This totals about 80 columns in total.

Comment: why doesn't a patient just have a list of flags associated with them?

Comment: don't worry, I get what you are trying to do, a patient does have a list of flags, and the flag tells you what table/row/column it's flagging.

Comment: That's correct. The table describes which column in which table should have which value in order to raise the flag. It doesn't seem to be the best approach though and wondering if there is anything better.

Comment: its tricky,  either you will hit the database hard, or memory....but it's all because you are trying to find flags on data pull,  would be easier to have flags raised when you push new data in.   Only issue is when you create a new flag you have to evaluate all existing data

Comment: So by creating a new table (say PatientFlag) and when the data is captured, populate that table?

Comment: I find this interesting, could you show-verbalize few columns (attributes) from each table -- at least those that can be flagged?

Comment: Sorry to be the one to be irritating, but is there a particular reason you're trying to wire this in on the database level? If there is a covering application / front end this is where such business logic should be - on loading of given patients file, determine if flag should exist. It will be faster, able to be more adaptable, and supports a better separation of concerns.

Answer (score 0):

You can add three fields to PatientMedicalHistory table: organ, disease, criticality.

When a patient comes in with a problem, you can pull patient history based on the same organ or disease presented in the current episode where the criticality meets a certain threshold. What you are doing here is classifying your patient history data so it relates to the current episode data.